# Java(ME) SQLlite vicious circle on Datatype Mismatch

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, sqlite

I am trying to obtain a float value from my Database

The following checks if its null else returns 1; (works if null in DB but errors if a float)

```
month =  row.getString(39) != null ? row.getFloat(39): 1;
```

On the other hand, the following gets float directly. (works if float in DB but errors if null)

```
float test = row.getFloat(39);
```

How would I go about obtaining a float from the DB, and in the case of a null, return a default value. I cant get it in either format as it causes errors when in a diff format.

Preferably without changing the SQL statement. As since there are 45 variables, it would get far too big, messy and unmanageable. I havent looked into it, but I assume with SQL I can do some kind of `IFNULL(field,default)`. Or maybe this is the best way... Although Id probably need `AS field` on the end too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work for any data type. Using getObject and checking if it is null. Even in the case of floats, where `!= null` would otherwise be invalid comparison.

```
month =  row.getObject(39) != null ? row.getFloat(39): 1;
```